# Can I delete am element from my AVRO schema

Tags: avro

Can I delete an element from my AVRO schema, see the enum below, can I remove it?  Reason is I want to add a list type instead which can take multiple values from the same enum.

```html
"fields": [{
   "name": "etype",
   "type":
   {
    "type": "enum",
    "name": "EFilter",
    "symbols" : ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR"]
   },
   "doc": "event types"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the Schema Registry?

If so, you could try removing the field and post the new schema against the latest version of the schema

https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#heading2-4

Removing a field is considered a backwards compatible change.

One option is to just add your new list field, then populate the enum with some dummy value during serialization, and ignore it during deserialization.

Comment: The documentation says that you can remove the field if your compatibility type is set to BACKWARD [link](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/avro.html)